# How to connect Windows 10 (joined to Samba) to a Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-10, samba, microsoft-account

After joining Windows 10 (1511) to a Samba domain, domain users are unable to sign in to the Microsoft store. It just fails with an unspecific error. This not only affects the store app, but also the user profile settings (where you connect your local account to your Microsoft account). Even Visual Studio 2015 hangs with a white dialog when trying to log in. Any connection to a Microsoft account seems to be impossible.

A related issue is that the RDP client takes an unusual long time to start, but when its there, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you encountering the error code `0x80090345` when you launch Windows Credential Manager by chance?

Comment: To test this, I set ProtectionPolicy to 0, but the Credential Manager seems to work fine. I didn't try to start it before I applied the work-around, so I can't tell whether it was initially broken. But that code seems familiar, I'd bet that this is the code Windows Live Mail 2012 showed me when trying to add new accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Open the registry editor (regedit.exe), navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb` and add a new DWORD subkey `ProtectionPolicy` with the value `1`. I have no idea why this works, so more elaborate explanations are welcome.

Comment: The following article explains the reason it works, ["To work around this problem, set the value of the ProtectionPolicy registry entry to 1 to enable local backup of the MasterKey instead of requiring a RWDC in the following registry subkey:"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3000850), it just does not explain the reason it be required on a Windows 10 machine, since the support article only applies to Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Windows Server 2012 R2 machines.

Comment: This also fixed my issues with Outlook 2016, where I was unable to add IMAP accounts.

Comment: Be sure the change, and the result of that key, is acceptable.  You are changing on something is working be sure you understand what that is.